# Is my laptop compatible with an SED SSD?

Tags: ssd, self-encrypting-drive

So I recently got a refurbished [Acer Nitro AN515-42](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NH.Q4TAA.001). Not the greatest gaming machine but it was cheap. I wanted to upgrade to an ssd so I tried to put in a PM961 I had sitting around only to find out the laptop doesn't support nvme drives. So I go shopping and end up purchasing this [Micron 512GB SATA m.2 drive](https://www.mydigitaldiscount.com/micron-512gb-1100-tlc-3d-nand-sata-iii-6gbps-80mm-2280ss-m.2-client-ssd-with-conformal-coating-fips-140-2-level-2-validated-sed-mtfddav512tbn-1ar15fcyy/). It has a conformal coating which I thought was cool and FIPS 140-2 L2 Validation which I didn't know much about but the price seemed like a decent deal. Now, being the not so smart person I am sometimes, I started doing my research after I paid for it. Came across this [tech quickie video from 6 years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnrawTYA9eA&feature=youtu.be&t=36) where he said the tricky part about SED's is finding out if your laptop is compatible. Does anyone know if that's still true? I've tried doing some research but it's been difficult trying to find an answer to my specific questions. Will it work with my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not self-encryption - worst case the drive would work fine but not take advantage of self encryption.

It is likely that the drive will work but some important encryption functionality (entering password on boot) wont. Thats not as bad as it sounds as you can still use bitlocker or equivalent software encryption, which I believe is hardware accellerated anyway, and actually more secure.

Comment: That's good news for me to hear! I honestly just got it because it was a decently cheap ssd. Whether or not the encryptions work doesn't matter to me too much. I just didn't want a repeat of my nvme where I put it in and the laptop doesn't even recognize it in bios. Thank-you!